# Docrtine 2 Hydration with Composite Keys

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have 3 entities:

1.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="uid")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductLabel", mappedBy="product")
     */
    protected $labels;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->labels = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addLabels(Collection $labels) {
        foreach ($labels as $label) {
            $label->setProduct($this);
            $this->labels->add($label);
        }
    }

    public function removeLabels(Collection $labels) {
        foreach ($labels as $label) {
            $label->setProduct(null);
            $this->labels->removeElement($label);
        }
    }

    public function getLabels() {
        return $this->labels;
    }

}
```

2.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_label")
 */
class ProductLabel
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="uid")
     */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Label")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="label_id", referencedColumnName="uid")
     */
    protected $label;

    public function setProduct($product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    public function setLabel($label)
    {
        $this->label = $label;
    }

    public function getLabel()
    {
        return $this->label;
    }

}
```

3.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="label")
 */

class Label {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="uid")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $title;

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }



}
```

And I'm trying to hydrate Product with Labels:

```
    $hydrator = new DoctrineObject($this->getEntityManager());
    $entity = new \Application\Entity\Product();
    $data = [
        'id' => 1,
        'title' => 'asdasd',
        'labels' => [
            [ 'product' => 1, 'label' => 1],
            [ 'product' => 1, 'label' => 2],
            [ 'product' => 1, 'label' => 3],
        ]
    ];
    $entity = $hydrator->hydrate($data, $entity);
    $this->getEntityManager()->merge($entity);
    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
```

But I have no changes in DB. I only get 4 SELECT queries from product_label table. 
Where is my mistake? Is it possible to use composite keys in this way?

Comment: What is the 2nd Entity used for? You only need to define the Product and Label entity. M:N is handled by doctrine2 internally, check the ManyToMany association

Comment: I have to use 1:N + 1:M instead of M:N because of client-side (ExtJS). The second reason - there are some cases with additional data that I need to store in mediator table.

Answer (score 1):

`'labels' => [
            [ 'product' => 1, 'label' => 1],
            [ 'product' => 1, 'label' => 2],
            [ 'product' => 1, 'label' => 3],
]`

This should not be in array. it should be instance of the label class
create a instance for the label class and set the values to that entity instead of Array

`should be instance of the class (ie) label instance should be passed`